Excel, while loop with variable loops
Good evening all,
I have a table in columns "A" and "B".  It is known as a BOM (Bill of Material) and column "A" is the parent of column "B" the child.  Some Codes have a child which may also have a child etc etc BUT they do not always have the same amount of levels.  In my example table A001 has two children of "A005" and "A006", each then has their own MCode child.  However, A002 does not have any child ACode and only has the child "M002".

I have tried various loops to convert the table in columns "A" and "B" into the table in columns "D" to "G" but the dynamic levels the children goto means I just cant get it to work.  Some investigation suggests a recursive function but am unable to implement despite various attempts.
Any support appreciated (not worried about the formatting in columns "D" to "G" but have put it in to aid understanding).  If you have any questions to aid understanding of my request then I am happy to answer any of them.
Many thanks, Alan.

This question is similar to: Flatten Parent Child Hierarchy in Excel (using formula or VBA). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Many thanks for the suggestion.  Sadly the options on the link makes very little sense.  Option 1 just errors even with a straight copy and paste.  Option 2 is way above my head and then option 3 I have no idea where the functions are supposed to be put.  All in all, safe to say I am lost completely.

Thanks for the fun challenge (love recursion :)
Recursion in Excel has some limitations, but this might work for your needs.
Please define a named formula (all_my_children) in Name Manager (we need to use it for recursive formulas) in the example I have created a table for the data named Tree.
all_my_children=
=LAMBDA(p, DROP(REDUCE("r", p, LAMBDA(acc,cur, LET(c, FILTER(Tree[Child], Tree[Parent] = cur), VSTACK(acc, IF(AND(ISERROR(c)), cur, HSTACK(cur, VSTACK(all_my_children(c)))))))), 1))

=LAMBDA(p,
    DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "r",
            p,
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                LET(
                    c, FILTER(Tree[Child], Tree[Parent] = cur),
                    VSTACK(
                        acc,
                        IF(AND(ISERROR(c)), cur, HSTACK(cur, VSTACK(all_my_children(c))))
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        1
    )
)

And then to get the result, (entered in E1 in the example):
=LET(
    first_level, UNIQUE(
        FILTER(Tree[Parent], MAP(Tree[Parent], LAMBDA(a_, AND(a_ <> Tree[Child]))))
    ),
    result, IFNA(all_my_children(first_level), ""),
    VSTACK("Level " & SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(result)), result)
)

Please let know know if any explanation is needed.


Although @nkalvi has provided a very nice answer, here is my result from the previous question as requested:

using Bomm
=IF(
    COUNTIF(Range1, Parent) = 0,
    hReplace({"", "", "", ""}, Level, Parent),
    REDUCE(
        hReplace({"", "", "", ""}, Level, Parent),
        FILTER(Range2, Range1 = Parent),
        LAMBDA(a, c, VSTACK(a, Bomm(c, Level + 1, Range1, Range2)))
    )
)

and hReplace
=LET(seq, SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(array)), IF(seq = pos, with, array))

In answer to your question the functions Bomm and hReplace have to be defined in the Name Manager, so it looks like this:

and this:

although I actually used the Advanced Formula Environment

The previous question only asked for four levels so M0001 is omitted in the above results. You can easily modify Bomm for five levels:
=IF(
    COUNTIF(Range1, Parent) = 0,
    hReplace({"", "", "", "", ""}, Level, Parent),
    REDUCE(
        hReplace({"", "", "", "", ""}, Level, Parent),
        FILTER(Range2, Range1 = Parent),
        LAMBDA(a, c, VSTACK(a, Bomm(c, Level + 1, Range1, Range2)))
    )
)

